# How to print the newline character instead of actually going to newline

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code, which parses and replace whenever it finds a pattern in the string.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n5";
        String newstr = str.replaceAll("(?<=nv13=)(.*\n?)(?=\n8)", "hello");
        System.out.println(newstr);
    }
}
```

I expect an output of

```
nv13=hello\n8nv13=hello\8nv13=hello\n8nv13=hello8nv13=hello\n8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n5
```

but,instead, I get

```
nv13=hello
8nv13=hello
8nv13=hello
8nv13=hello
8nv13=hello
8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r
5
```

What am I missing the above code to fix the \n , to actually print it out in the string without going to the next line ?

Comment: `String newstr = str.replaceAll("(?<=nv13=)(.*\n?)(?=\n8)", "hello").replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");`

Comment: Printing the newline character _makes the terminal go to the next line_. Are you wanting to print the escape code `\n` instead of the newline character?

Answer (score 0):

```
newstr = newstr.replace("\n", "\\n");
```

You can escape the `\` like this `\\`. So this will print `\n` and not actually go on a new line.

Output:

```
nv13=hello\n8nv13=hello\n8nv13=hello\n8nv13=hello\n8nv13=hello\n8nv13=4t543r523w4r2w3e4r\n5
```